# Can I change locale on Stateful widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to change calendar language from English to Korean. I think I don't have any errors while I type this code. But my locale isn't changed. Don't know why it didn't work.

this is my code. I already changed **'pubspec.yaml'**

```
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart'; // library

Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
return  MaterialApp(
  localizationsDelegates: [
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  supportedLocales: [
    const Locale('ko', 'KR'),
  ],
  home: buildHomePage(),
);

Future<void> _selectrequestDate(BuildContext context) async {
final DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialDate: requestDate,
    firstDate: DateTime(2015),
    lastDate: DateTime(2050));
if (pickedDate != null && pickedDate != requestDate)
  setState(() {
    requestDate = pickedDate;
  });
```

How can I fix this problem? If I try this on new project, it works well.

Comment: Self answer to a dumb question. I didn't know I have to put localization option to main.dart. I did it to wrong files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization/changelog) packages, because on the lastest version the packages provides `startLocale` which overides device locale.

Comment: Thanks I will try it! I don't know this library yet.

Comment: Yes, you must try that library